# Macbook Pro Yosemite l Bootcamp Issue

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

So for whatever reason, I am having a difficult time **SAVING** the Windows Support Software.  I tried restarting the process, but it didn't seem to go anywhere.  My bootcamp appears to be stuck on this step, and I am not sure why. Any suggestions?

Comment: What type of Macbook do you have? (Year AND model) What error messages was BCA giving you?

Comment: It's a mid 2012 Macbook Pro

2.5Ghz Intel Core i5

8 Gigs of ram

As for the Error, there isn't one.  It just seems stuck on Saving windows support software

Comment: Oh, and it's a 13 inch!

Comment: Installing Windows 8 or 7?

Comment: I'm installing Windows 7, however it shouldn't matter as I am having issues with the support software, as opposed to the OS itself.

Answer (score 1):

If the Windows Support Software from the Boot Camp Assistant is not downloading and/or returns an error, you can download the software manually for the machine depending on the year/make of your Macbook, iMac, or Mac Pro.

This list can be found on the [Apple KBase](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048).

Based on you having a Mid-2012 13" MacBook, you would be looking for one of the following downloads:

[Windows 7/8 64-bit](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720) (BC Support Software v5)
[Windows 7 32-bit](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1635) (BC Support Software v4)

Follow the instructions on the KBase article for installing the support software, and build your Win7 disk with the Support Software box unchecked in BCA.